# DAO classes Singleton or Prototype Which is the best approach

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am working on DAO Layer and writing classes. These classes will be injected in Service layer using spring IOC. What is the best approach Singleton/Prototype (DAO classes does not have any state )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they don't have state, it really doesn't matter much. Leave them as singletons, so you won't have multiple unnecessary instances of the same DAO.

Note that, if your services are themselves singletons, making the DAO prototypes will only create one instance per service where it's injected anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't making them singletons cause a potential bottleneck

Comment: Why would it? No, it wouldn't.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't actually meant to get posted :) I don't have experience with Spring and was wondering if concurrency access could be an issue if spring manages access to the singleton ala. EJB containers. I then went to look that up and learnt that it doesn't and there wouldn't be a bottleneck.